# Pagination on new-answers-old-questions off by one

Tags: bug, status-completed, 10k-tools

When I go to https://stackoverflow.com/tools/new-answers-old-questions?page=2 I actually get page 1 - that is, requesting both page 1 and page 2 URLs give the same results, and highlight the "1" in the paginator.

For each page requested, I actually get the previous one, so https://stackoverflow.com/tools/new-answers-old-questions?page=5 gives page 4, etc.

Note that this means that pressing "Next" in the page display at the bottom goes nowhere - you're on page 2 and you click next to ask for page 3, you get back page 2.  So clicking next asks for page 3, which gives you page 2....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oops? Fixed in the next build!